# How to split Dictionary with tuples into three different strings in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following represents my code:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> headCS = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> { };

while (results.Read())
{
    headCS.Add(results["ID"].ToString(),
               new Tuple<string, string>(results["TEXT_HEADER"].ToString(), 
                                         results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString()));
}

valueIntroduction.InnerHtml = headCS.Values.ElementAt(0).ToString();
```

In `valueIntroduction.InnerHtml`, it has both header as well as content. Now I want to split into Header separately and Content separately. But I want to get the header separately in a string and content separately in a string. Any idea how to achieve this?

Eg Output for the above is `(100, (Intro, My name is vimal))`. "100" represents key, "Intro" represents Header, "My name is vimal" represents Content.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: To split them use a # knife

Answer (score 0):

To get the values out of a `Dictionary` you need to do a `foreach` over the `KeyValuePair` as follows:

```
        Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> headCS = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

        List<string> key  = new List<string>();
        List<string> header = new List<string>();
        List<string> content = new List<string>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<string,string>> item in headCS)
        {
           //print values to console
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", item.Key, item.Value.Item1, item.Value.Item2);

            //store values for in another form just as an example of what they represent
            key.Add(item.Key);
            header.Add(item.Value.Item1);
            content.Add(item.Value.Item2);
        }
```